# Remote WOL over internet

Tags: wake-on-lan

I was wondering, is there a way to wake up my PC over the Internet? I read some tutorials to wake it up over local LAN .. But what about through the Internet?

Note: I have a dynamic DNS registered via http://dyndns.com so I can use it to redirect to my home IP. Also, I can request static IP from my ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you can tell your router to forward the packet. This may need one to run several telnet commands on most consumer NAT devices.

Comment: any tutorial on how to achieve that? I have a 3Com router.

Comment: Ok, you need to be able to forward UDP port 9 to the subnet broadcast address, then to wake you send a UDP packet to port 9 of the routers public IP containing 6 bytes of FF and then 16 repeats of the MAC address of the computer you want to wake.

Comment: Basically you need to get the final router to convert it to broadcast packet which aren't usually routed across subnets (for very good reason)

Comment: Finally, routers tend to not allow this sort of thing as if it's not handled properly, the same technique can be used to pull off a kind of DDoS attack called a smurf attack against such a network.